# When x and y inserted fill GEOMETRY automatically

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The idea is when `Longitude` and `Latitude` inserted `Location` has to fill with correct info. But when I try to write code of this one I get error about `Column names in each table must be unique. Column name '[Location]' in table 'Points' is specified more than once.`

Here's the code block.

```
ALTER TABLE Points
ADD [Location] AS (CONVERT(GEOMETRY, CASE WHEN Longitude<> 0
                                    AND Latitude<> 0
                               THEN GEOMETRY::STGeomFromText('POINT('
                                                          + CONVERT(VARCHAR, Longitude)
                                                          + ' '
                                                          + CONVERT(VARCHAR, Latitude)
                                                          + ')', 4238)
                               ELSE NULL
                          END))
```

So it's the `Points` table

```
CREATE TABLE Points(
Id int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
Route_Id int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [Routes](Id) ON DELETE CASCADE NOT NULL,
Title nvarchar(30) NOT NULL,
[Description] nvarchar NOT NULL ,
Latitude FLOAT NOT NULL,
Longitude FLOAT NOT NULL,
[Location] geometry ,
Point_Image IMAGE 
)
```

Comment: The error means you already have a column in the table named `Location`. Post your `CREATE TABLE` statement if you need help resolving the error.

Comment: You have one column named `[Location]` (before `Point_Image`) and you are trying to add another column with the same name. Do you want to update the data in the existing column or modify that column to be a computed column?

Comment: @RazvanSocol i want to update `Location` avtomatically

Comment: A couple of things - 1. I'd take a look at the `Point()` static method as a less verbose way of defining your point (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/point-geometry-data-type?view=sql-server-2017) 2. Whenever I see someone using `geometry` for something that represents locations on Earth, I get a little itchy (since it doesn't take into account things like the Earth's curvature, crossing the Prime Meridian, and other weird things about doing the calculations on an oblate spheroid).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to update now the values in the existing `[Location]` column you can use:

```
UPDATE  dbo.Points
SET     Location = CONVERT(GEOMETRY, 
    CASE WHEN Longitude <> 0 AND Latitude <> 0 
        THEN geometry::STGeomFromText(
            'POINT(' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, Longitude) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, Latitude) + ')'
            , 4238)
        ELSE NULL
    END)
```

If you want to have a computed column which will always return the computed data, you should drop the existing column and create another one:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Points DROP COLUMN Location
GO
ALTER TABLE Points ADD [Location] AS CONVERT(GEOMETRY, 
    CASE WHEN Longitude <> 0 AND Latitude <> 0 
        THEN geometry::STGeomFromText(
            'POINT(' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, Longitude) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, Latitude) + ')'
            , 4238)
        ELSE NULL
    END)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to insert `Longitude` and `Latitude` into `Location` column? if yes then the syntax written is incorrect.

you can try this, Not sure if this will solve your issue.

```
Insert into Points ([Location])values 
(select (CONVERT(GEOMETRY, CASE WHEN Longitude<> 0
                                    AND Latitude<> 0
                               THEN  
                                                          + CONVERT(VARCHAR, Longitude)
                                                          + ' '
                                                          + CONVERT(VARCHAR, Latitude)

                               ELSE NULL
                          END))
from Points)
```

Comment: Yes. I wanted to get when `Longitude` and `Latitude` inserted to table `Location` has to fill with correct data . How can i write this ?

Comment: Your code tries to insert new rows in the `Points` table, but fails because you added an extra `values` clause and you did not specify values for the other non-nullable columns.

Comment: ohh ok. Thank you!